# Batch file message popup, how to insert emoji?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, popup, message, emoji

`Write like this`

```
msg * "My emoji "
```

`But on popup I get`
msg * "My emoji (random symbols)"

How to write a specific emoji for batch file popup on windows 10?

Comment: Are you remembering to save the file as UTF-8 instead of the default ANSI?

Comment: In your script use `CHCP 65001` before the `msg` command. See [Change default code page of Windows console to UTF-8](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)

Comment: A batch file is processed by the Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` which __requires__ that a batch file to process is [character encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) with one byte per character with the [OEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_equipment_manufacturer) [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) defined by region/country configured for the used account. It is possible to get in a batch file the current code page number and store it in an environment variable and then change the character encoding to UTF-8 which uses 1-4 bytes per character.

Comment: All lines read from the batch file after changing to "code page" 65001 are interpreted by `cmd.exe` as UTF-8 encoded character stream until the command line is executed which restores the initial code page before leaving the batch file processing. However, `cmd.exe` is a console application and the Windows console is a pure text interface. So images for an emoji like in your question are not supported in this user interface at all. But it could be that `%SystemRoot%\System32\msg.exe` supports Unicode encoded text passed via the command line arguments to it and display them correct somehow.

Comment: I recommend to read also the Wikipedia pages about [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) and [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) to get the basic knowledge about character encoding which each programmer should have on using non ASCII characters in source code of a program or in a script.

Comment: Take a look at this [Display Unicode Emoji in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62437994/3080770)

Answer (score 6):

Based from the ***Mofi's comment***, you should change the code page to `65001` and the batch file will be saved as `UTF-8`

```
@echo off
chcp 65001>nul
Title Emoji 
msg * "My emoji "
pause
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! This has helped me to insert emojis in git commits which I would regularly do with a Windows batch file (`.bat`). I was about to give up. :D