How to embed Windows symbols (Win+;) into the code, to be printed on file and on screen?
On Windows when you press the Windows key and the semicolon button ";" you can chose for some colored symbol (e.g. ) and use it on documents, notepad, posts on social: anything.
Now, I want to embed these symbols into Powershell so that they can be printed on screen
Write-Host "important"

Or saved on text files
On VSC I can insert the symbols as they are and they are correctly represented into the code
$Footer = "`n*CONCEPTS*`n`n`n*KEY MOMENTS*`n"

But when the file is generated, I just get "??" instead of the symbols.
Here's my PowerShell version:

NOTE:
I searched in the internet but I didn't find anything about this. perhaps I don't use the correct terminology to identify and isolate this case.

What you're describing is just the emoji picker, not "Windows symbols". Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45624030/3001761?

@jonrsharpe I did write "I searched in the internet but I didn't find anything about this. perhaps I don't use the correct terminology to identify and isolate this case. Any suggested topic by StackOveflow are not inherent this use case." but you removed it and you are asking me if I got that specific post.

It is the first link here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Display+Emoji+in+PowerShell

@luuk not any solution will be available if downvoting somebody asked for info and disclaiming that "perhaps I don't use the correct terminology to identify and isolate this case". Removed posts for such things = removed help for other ones.

@TormyVanCool: no clue what you are trying to say in above comment....

@Luuk: I think the message was: Questions that may not use the official terminology but use terms that users unfamiliar or only superficially familiar with the technology at hand may use intuitively can be valuable signposts for such users, i..e. they can guide them to the correct terminology and solutions.

hi @Luuk well to me these small dots or diamonds etc are symbols. Not emoji. Te word "emoticon" expresses Emotions in an Icon as the word suggests. My error was to consider the word "Emoji"  in an identical way. So: all what's not emotion-expression is a symbol (beside the fact that Emotics are still symbols). And indeed "Emoji" in Japanese (original language) means  "Symbol". So: I was not wrong at all to search for "symbol" but ok everything was under ONLY "EMoji" word. Semantic mistake then.
Who have put down my request, blatantly is born with the "knowledge inside". But. Sorry.

The indication given by @mathias R. Jessen about the switch -encode is paramount
Indeed by adding the switch -encode utf8 it correctly applies the symbol pasted into VSC as well.
So it's not necessary to have instructions like this
$orangeDiamond = [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F538)

In my foreach() cycle where the file txt is built line-by-line, just by adding the suggested switch, it worked out perfectly
Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "$mainStringOutput" -Encoding UTF8

This is valid for both: Powershell 5 and 7.
In my case $mainStringOutput is a string built into the foreach() cycle in this way
    $mainStringOutput= "  $a. $leftPart - $rightPart"

The text file is automatically saved as UTF-8 with BOM in order for Windows PowerShell (v5.1) to read it correctly it means that it contains the required text and the correct format for the so called "Emoji" ("Symbols" in English).
By reopening it with NOtepad, Notepad++, VSC, the Emojis are correctly displayed.
No need to do of anything else. Top!

tl;dr

In order to use literal, arbitrary Unicode characters (e.g. ) in PowerShell source code, the source-code file must be saved with a Unicode character encoding, typically UTF-8.

However, in order for Windows PowerShell (PowerShell versions up to v5.1) to read such files correctly, they must be encoded as UTF-8 with BOM (by contrast, PowerShell (Core) 7 also recognizes BOM-less UTF-8 files correctly).

A pitfall is that modern code editors (sensibly) default to BOM-less UTF-8, so you may have to (re-)save your file as UTF-8 with BOM manually; this answer shows how to configure Visual Studio Code, via its PowerShell extension, to default to UTF-8 with BOM when creating PowerShell source-code files.



Similarly, in order to save strings that contain arbitrary Unicode characters to a file, a Unicode character encoding must be used.

PowerShell (Core) 7, the cross-platform, install-on-demand edition, uses a Unicode encoding by default, consistently, namely BOM-less UTF-8, with any file-writing cmdlet / the redirection operator, >.

In order to create UTF-8 files with BOM, for cross-PowerShell-edition compatibility, pass an -Encoding utf8BOM argument to file-writing cmdlets.


Windows PowerShell, the legacy, Windows-only, ships-with-Windows edition whose latest and last version is v5.1, uses varying encodings, depending on the specific file-writing cmdlet used / whether the redirection operator, > is used.

Notably, Set-Content defaults to the legacy system locale's ANSI encoding, which is not capable of representing all Unicode characters, whereas Out-File / > defaults to UTF-16LE encoding (with BOM), which many CLIs do not recognize, but PowerShell does.

Passing an -Encoding utf8 argument to file-writing cmdlets invariably creates UTF-8 files with BOM. If this is undesired, workarounds are required - see this answer.






Upshot:

In order to use arbitrary non-ASCII-range Unicode characters in PowerShell source code, the PowerShell engine must recognize the source-code file encoding correctly, and the safe, cross-edition choice is to save source code in UTF-8 with BOM files - see this answer.

Mathias' answer shows you how to alternatively represent such Unicode characters programmatically, expressed via ASCII-range characters only, for scenarios where only ASCII encoding can be assumed as the lowest common denominator when a file is read.


Passing an -Encoding utf8 argument to a file-writing cmdlet reliably produces UTF-8 output files capable of encoding all Unicode characters, though in Windows PowerShell the resulting files will be UTF-8 with BOM, whereas in PowerShell 7 (where this argument is redundant) they'll be BOM-less UTF-8.
For file-reading cmdlets, -Encoding utf8 (redundant in PowerShell 7) ensures that input files without BOM are decoded as UTF-8.



Background information

In memory, PowerShell is always capable of representing all Unicode characters, because it uses .NET strings which are composed of UTF-16 code units (note that with , i.e. a character outside the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane, two code units are required to encode it, i.e. a so-called surrogate pair).

Potential misinterpretation / loss of information only comes into play when reading or writing external, binary representations of strings, via character encodings, typically when reading / writing files:

when reading strings from files, notably including how the PowerShell engine reads source code.

when writing strings to files, with cmdlets such as Set-Content or Out-File / >




The two PowerShell editions - the legacy, ships-with-Windows Windows PowerShell edition (powershell.exe, whose latest and final version is 5.1.x) vs. the install-on-demand, cross-platform PowerShell (Core) 7 edition (pwsh, version 7.x) - differ with respect to their default character encodings, which apply - on reading - to files that do not have a BOM or which are read without an -Encoding argument, as well as - on writing - to files written without an -Encoding argument:

Windows PowerShell:

On reading, in the absence of a BOM / an -Encoding argument, assumes the legacy system locale's active ANSI encoding, both with Get-Content and with respect to reading source code.

Typically, the active ANSI encoding is an 8-bit single-byte encoding such as Windows-1252 on US-English systems (the same applies analogously to the active OEM encoding, such as CP437). That is, such encodings are invariably limited to 256 characters overall, and thereby by definition incapable of representing all Unicode characters.

There is a way to make UTF-8 both the active ANSI and OEM encoding system-wide, but doing so has far-reaching consequences - see this answer.



On writing, Set-Content too defaults to the active ANSI encoding, though other cmdlets use different encodings; notably, Out-File / > uses "Unicode" (UTF-16LE); for a comprehensive overview of the wildly inconsistent default encodings in Windows PowerShell, see the bottom section of this answer.

Using -Encoding utf8 on writing invariably creates a UTF-8 file with BOM; to achieve the same in PowerShell 7, use -Encoding utf8BOM (see next point).




PowerShell 7:

This edition commendably consistently defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8, meaning that BOM-less files are consistently read as UTF-8, and file-writing cmdlets that aren't passed an -Encoding argument consistently produce BOM-less UTF-8 files.




It follows from the above that for cross-edition compatibility:

Input files, including source-code files, should be saved as UTF-8 with BOM (UTF-16LE with BOM would work too, but bloats the file size).

As noted, modern editors default to BOM-less UTF-8, so care must be taken to save PowerShell source-code files as UTF-8 with BOM.

If you're running Windows PowerShell and know a given file to be BOM-less UTF-8, pass an -Encoding utf8 argument on reading, e.g. to Get-Content.



Output files, too, should be saved as UTF-8 with BOM, which requires passing -Encoding utf8 in Windows PowerShell vs. -Encoding utf8BOM in PowerShell 7.

However, note that in the Unix world, including with respect to Windows-ported utilities of Unix heritage, a UTF-8 BOM may cause problems, as Unix(-heritage) utilities generally do not expect a BOM and treat it as data instead.

To make Windows PowerShell produce BOM-less UTF-8 files too requires workarounds - see this answer.





Thank you for your complete explanation. indeed it's very useful for who doesn't use VSC for instance, to have a full picture.
However yesterday I found the way to make it work just by pasting the emoji inside VSC, as you can see from my self-answer, just by using Powershell 5.1.x since the 7.xx doesn't start by right click on the .ps1 > open with POwershell. It start always the 5.xx. And once the script is finished (yesterday I did), I need quick operational actions and not "click here-&-there". Just right click > Run with PowerShell.

@TormyVanCool: VSC is ultimately incidental to your question; like most modern code editors, it defaults to creating BOM-less UTF-8 files, so to support all Unicode chars. in Windows PowerShell (v5.1), you need to save source-code files as UTF-8 with BOM. Similarly, if you use Set-Content or Add-Content in Windows PowerShell, you must use -Encoding utf8 in order to create UTF-8 files (which, unlike in PowerShell 7, will invariably be UTF-8 with BOM). I've updated the answer to make these points clearer.

yes exactly as I wrote on my answer. First paste the symbol (emoji whatsoever it's called) ... and then add the switch -Encoding utf8

I specified it. I mean in the post I said "or saved in text files" which implies the TXT (as "emoji" implies "symbols" and viceversa), and I thought the PowerShell instructions given are clear, at least in this use case.
In my answering post I specified the instruction 'Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "$mainStringOutput" -Encoding UTF8'  that, united to what I said into the post, is what I need: save it in a TXT file. And yes also visible on Write-host (and eventually  it is). now I'm working with that script making what I needed :-)

@TormyVanCool: Your answer says "saved as UTF8", which is missing a crucial detail: it must be UTF-8 with BOM in order for Windows PowerShell (v5.1) to read it correctly - that editors such as VSC read it correctly even without a BOM is not enough. Unless you add this information to your answer (too - it obviously is already part of this answer), I recommend against accepting your own answer.

For code generation scenarios where you can't predict the source code encoding, a couple of options are available.
PowerShell 7 has support for wide unicode char descriptions in expandable string literals using the `u{XXXXXXXX} syntax, where XXXXXXXX is a (optionally zero-truncated) hexadecimal value corresponding to the unicode character you want:
$orangeDiamond = "`u{1F538}"
Write-Host "`n*CONCEPTS*`n${orangeDiamond}`n`n*KEY MOMENTS*`n${orangeDiamond}"

In earlier versions, >16-bit characters can be parsed and converted to a string with [char]::ConvertFromUtf32:
$orangeDiamond = [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F538)
Write-Host "`n*CONCEPTS*`n${orangeDiamond}`n`n*KEY MOMENTS*`n${orangeDiamond}"


For writing wide unicode characters to disk, make sure you pick an encoding that supports them (eg. UTF8 or UTF16):
"`n*CONCEPTS*`n${orangeDiamond}`n`n*KEY MOMENTS*`n${orangeDiamond}" |Set-Content path\to\output.txt -Encoding UTF8
# or
"`n*CONCEPTS*`n${orangeDiamond}`n`n*KEY MOMENTS*`n${orangeDiamond}" |Set-Content path\to\output.txt -Encoding Unicode


Unfortunately I got the same result on the produced TXT file. "??". i'm using PS 5.xx .. So I followed your sedon suggestion

You say "on the produced TXT file", but nothing I've posted writes to a file - can you expand on what exactly you're doing?

Iworte into the post. I need it displayed -and- also saved into Text files.

the last mod you've made it works. Thank you.
